# Create a view something similar to pinterest

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am working on an application related to news feeds where I need to GUI design like Pinterest application as in attachment picture image ,There are thee things (menus) at top like Search , Pinterest and Profile ,I want the same that should be change by swapping and click , User can switch among (search,Pinterest and profile ) top menu by click and swapping .Anyone can guide how I can do it ? I try tab view but unable to add swapping , anyone can guide me better way ?

[image: Change body by swapping and click]

Answer (score 0):

For such a layout, I would recommend [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). Make sure to download the [demo application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample) and look at the code of the swipable tabs implementation. That may be exactly what you're looking for.

For an easy customization of the tabs in there, you'll find the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) helpful.